# Smooth anchor scrolling on ajax loaded pages (cannot read property 'top')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make my anchor link scroll smoothly and no matter what I do I can't get them to work. The pages are loaded by ajax and I've placed the code on the loaded pages to no effect and on the main page (doing the loading) and nothing.

Here's my main page code:

```
$(document).on('click','a[href^="#"]',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop':  $target.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

here's the code on the loaded page (simplified):

```
<a href="#bottom" alt="bottom" id="btn-bottom">click</a>
<!--
content goes here
-->
<a name="bottom" id="bottom"></a>
```

Comment: it does work whats the problem you are having https://fiddle.jshell.net/2sobnk98/

Comment: it doesn't work on my end. on the sample you provided, that's all loading up on that one page, with mine, I have 2 pages... (index.html) and (plan.html). index.html loads plan.html's content into a div. The scroll doesn't work when it's loaded :\

Comment: you might have to add all the code for those files as i am unable to get why still if they are 2 diff files all you are doing is loading content into div with ajax and i am adding it from a literal and that is also inside the div by using append the thing to note is that the animation should be called after the content is loaded via ajax in `success` callback rather than binding it to the click button